# Noto Color Emojis look super huge

Tags: fonts, emoji

Recently I forced all of my system fonts to either use Noto Sans or Noto Color Emoji. However, `charmap` showed huge fallback emojis that looked like this: [image: <code>charmap</code>]

Problem exists in Firefox and even Chrome (Chrome uses Color Emoji). [This website gives a normal result (no huge emojis).](http://eosrei.github.io/emojione-color-font/full-demo.html) My question is: How do I fix this?

Update: 2nd case

[image: 2nd case]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/81wyq2/giant_emoji_in_terminal/dv617z8/

`sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/`

Then reload fontconfig: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig`

Comment: You don't actually need to reload fontconfig. Restarting the application in question should suffice.